# Calculus III: Find the points of the curve...

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, analytic-geometry, curves

I have to find the points of the curve $$r\left( t \right) =\left( t,{ t }^{ 2 },{ t }^{ 3 } \right) $$ where the osculating plane passes through the point $\left( 2,-\frac { 1 }{ 3 } ,-6 \right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the osculating plane is made of points of the form:
$$ (t,t^2,t^3)+\lambda_1(1,2t,3t^2)+\lambda_2(0,2,6t) $$
we have to solve, with respect to $t$, the polynomial system:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 2 &=& t+\lambda_1 \\ -\frac{1}{3} &=& t^2+2\lambda_1 t+2\lambda_2\\ -6 &=& t^3+3t^2\lambda_1+6t\lambda_2\end{array}\right.$$
that is equivalent to:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 2 &=& t+\lambda_1 \\ -\frac{13}{3} &=& 2\lambda_2-\lambda_1^2\\ -14 &=& 3t(2\lambda_2-\lambda_1^2)-\lambda_1^3\end{array}\right.$$
by subtracting from the second equation the square of the first one and by subtracting from the third equation the cube of the first one. By simplifying further:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} 2 &=& t+\lambda_1 \\ \frac{13}{3} &=& \lambda_1^2-2\lambda_2\\ 14 &=& 13t+\lambda_1^3\end{array}\right.$$
so we have $\lambda_1^3-13\lambda_1+12=0$, from which $\lambda_1\in\{-4,1,3\}$ follows.

Now the first equation simply gives $t\in\{-1,1,6\}$. Done.

Comment: Nice dude, thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the osculating plane at $r(t)$ is generated by the vectors $\mathbf{T}(t)$ and $\mathbf{N}(t)$ (tangent and normal). Hence, the binormal vector $\mathbf{B}(t)$ is normal to the osculating plane. Remember that this curve is not parametrized by arc-length, so we have: $$\mathbf{B}(t) = \frac{r'(t) \wedge r''(t)}{\|r'(t) \wedge r''(t)\|}$$ 
You want the values of $t$ that satisfies the equation: $$\left\langle r(t)- \left(2, -\frac{1}{3}, -6 \right), \mathbf{B}(t) \right\rangle = 0$$
Then, to find the points on the curve, compute $r(t)$ for the values of $t$ you found above.

---

We have $r'(t) = (1,2t,3t^2)$ and $r''(t) = (0,2,6t)$. From this, we get $r'(t) \wedge r''(t) = (6t^2,-6t, 2)$. If the vector $r(t)- \left(2, -\frac{1}{3}, 0 \right)$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf{B}(t)$, it is orthogonal to $r'(t) \wedge r''(t)$ too. We have to solve: $$\begin{align} \left\langle r(t)- \left(2, -\frac{1}{3}, -6 \right), r'(t) \wedge r''(t) \right\rangle = 0\end{align} \\ \langle (t - 2, t^2 + (1/3), t^3 + 6), (6t^2,-6t, 2)\rangle = 0$$
which doesn't seems too hard.

Comment: The normalization introduces ugliness. It is better to work directly with derivatives with respect to the $t$ parameter, since $\frac{dr}{dt}$ and $\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}$ both lie on the osculating plane.

Comment: I don't think it will be *too* ugly.. we have $r''(t) = (0, 2, 6t)$, so this zero will kill some stuff on the cross product. Well, it's something else for OP to think.

Comment: I would like to see the computations made this way just to check if they are comparable in length with the ones I made by just taking the first two partial derivatives with respect to $t$.

Comment: Well, it's instructive for us both.. I'll just set up the final equation, let's see how bad it gets.

Comment: I just realized we are stating the same thing, since we can just drop the normalization factor $\frac{1}{\|r'(t)\wedge r''(t)\|}$ out of the inner product that must be zero.

Comment: I realized that in the middle of the calculation, too. (;

Comment: (+1) So we just posted the same solution at the same time. Great timing :D

Comment: That's why I like maths! +1 for your answer too :D